# Please describe the `AIMD` please?

Tags: tcp

Hello I have don't really know the `TCP AIMD`.

I tried many Google search results put all of them were in **technical language** and is hard for me as **newbi**

So can someone please explain me the `TCP AIMD` in a ***easy language***???

Comment: Network Engineering is for professional questions only and learning material is off topic here. I think that Cisco has some online forums or email lists that are better suited for questions like this. Good luck in finding answers.

Comment: Do you even understand how and why TCP does windowing, and what that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIMD Stands for Additive Increase and Multiplicative Decrease.

```
Now Increase and Decrease of what?... Ans: Congestion Window size (CWND)
```

Let me take a step back and shed some light on few prerequisites.

Whenever, a sender has to send some traffic over the network without creating congestion and without worry of re-transmitting, it should see two things:

```
1. Client Receive Window size (RWS)
2. Congestion Window Size (CWND)
```

For faster transfer, a sender generally doesn't send a single packet and waits for the client to ack it and then send the next packet (Stop-And-Wait).

To figure out how many packets can be sent in burst without waiting for their acknowledgement, Sender uses `Receive window Size (RWS)`advertised by receiver in tcp-handshake. On the other hand, Sender detects congestion in the network by the number of re-transmission and decrements this number, which we call CWND i.e. `Congestion windows size`

When a congestion is detected by the sender, it definitely needs to slow down and hence reduce the size of its CWND. Congestion in the network is unpredictable so after reducing the CWND, there is a fair amount of chance that congestion in the network decreases and the sender can increase CWND.

For these reasons, sender starts with a low value of CWND and with every successful transmission it `additively increases` CWND e.g. 1,2,3,4... hoping that congestion won't occur. When the packets start getting dropped, it `reduces CWND multiplicatively`. This makes sure that for next transmission, possibility of congestion is pretty less and overall congestion in the network is sustainable.